# Updating code on production server when using Go

Tags: http, go, server

When I develop and update files on production server with PHP I just copy the files on the fly and everything seems to work without interrupting the server.

But if I am to update the code on the Go server and application and would need to kill the server, copy the src files to the server, run go install, and then start the server, this would interrupt the service, and if I do this quite often then it is going to look very bad for my users of the service.

How can I update files without the downtime when using Go with Go's http server?

Comment: Compile it locally (cross-compiling if necessary) and then copy the binary to the server. One file. You shouldn't need to compile it on your server.

Comment: would this lead to corruption of data because of simultaneous reads while overwriting or writes from users while overwriting the binary files?

Comment: Don't live overwrite. Copy to a temp location, stop the service (gracefully if you must), overwrite the old binary and start the replacement. There are more elegant ways to swap them but unless you really can't survive a few *seconds* of planned downtime they involve a lot more complexity. e.g. a socket manager like Einhorn

Comment: thank you very much, I will gracefully end things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grace library will allow you to do graceful restarts without annoyance for your users: https://github.com/facebookgo/grace

Yet in my experience restarting Go applications is so quick, unless you have an high traffic website it won't cause any trouble.

Comment: Thanks, I will use that!

Answer (score 2):

PHP is an [interpreted language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language), which means you provide your code in source format and the PHP interpreter will read it and execute it (it may create a more compact binary form so that it doesn't have to analyze the source again when needed).

Go is a [compiled language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language), it compiles into a native executable binary; going further it is *statically linked* which means every code and library your app is referring to is compiled and linked when the executable is created. This implies you can't just "drop-in" new go modules into a running application.

You have to stop your running application and start the new version. You can however minimize the downtime: only stop the running application when the new version of the executable is already created and ready to be run. You may choose to compile it on a remote machine and upload the binary to the server, or upload the source and compile it on the server, it doesn't matter.

With this you could decrease the downtime to a maximum of few seconds, which your users won't notice. Also you shouldn't update in every hour, you can't really achieve significant updates in just an hour of coding. You could schedule updates daily (or even less frequently), and you could schedule them for hours when your traffic is low.

If even a few seconds downtime is not acceptable to you, then you should look for platforms which handle this for you automatically without any downtime. Check out [Google App Engine - Go](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't do it in that order.  Copy and install first.  Then you could stop the old process and run the new one.

If you run multiple instances of your app, then you can do a rolling update, so that when you bounce one server, the other ones are still serving.  A similar approach is to do [blue-green deployments](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=blue-green%20deployment), which has the advantage that the code your active cluster is running is always homogeneous (whereas during a rolling deploy, you'll have a mixture until they've all rolled), and you can also do a blue-green deployment where you normally have only one instance of your app (whereas rolling requires more than one).  It does however require you to have double the instances during the blue-green switch.

One thing you'll want to take into consideration is any in-flight requests -- you may want to make sure that in-flight requests continue to go to old-code servers until their finished.

You can also look into Platform-as-a-Service solutions, that can automate a lot of this stuff for you, plus a whole lot more.  That way you're not ssh'ing into production servers and copying files around manually.  The [12 Factor App](http://12factor.net/) principles are always a good place to start when thinking about ops.